# Includes on html pages

Tags: javascript, html

i have an html page where i include a header who is implemented on another page. On loading, through the javascript code, the html page with header code is included on my main page.

Example:

Main.html:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#header").load("header.html");
        //$("#footer").load("footer.html");
    });
</script>
<body>
<div id='header'></div>

...

</body>
</html>
```

Now i have another html page - Header.html - where i define the navbar.

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar barra_superior">
    ...
    </nav>
```

But, with this solution the meta tag on header.html is applied to main.html too. My question is if i can apply the meta tag only on header.html.

Thanks

Comment: Did you include include jQuery?

Comment: You may not want to include the meta tag via jquery, it could confuse some search engines and web crawlers.

Comment: @Joao Ferreria, i suggest manipulation outside body would be good to do it in server side Javascript  like nodeJS or any server side scripting

Answer (score 0):

[`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) allows you to load a page fragment:

> The `.load()` method, unlike `$.get()`, allows us to specify a portion of
>   the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special
>   syntax for the `url` parameter. If one or more space characters are
>   included in the string, the portion of the string following the first
>   space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content
>   to be loaded.

So use it like this:

```
$("#header").load("header.html nav.navbar.barra_superior");
```

When this method executes, it retrieves the content of header.html, but then jQuery parses the returned document to find the nav element with the classes of navbar and barra_superior. This element, along with its contents, is inserted into the element with an ID of header, and the rest of the retrieved document is discarded. Therefore, the `<meta>` element from Header.html won't be inserted. If you want to insert more than the navbar from Header.html, you can specify the body element instead.